# Суммировать значения из столбца по условию другого столбца

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица 
 [![2 столбца: ИД и Значение][1]][1]

причем для каждого а всегда будет одно и тоже значение, то есть если а=5, то оно уже не поменяется, будет встречаться в таблице несколько раз. то же самое справедливо для каждого ИД. Надо найти сумму по полю VAL, но из каждой группы ID брать одно значение. то есть запрос будет такой 
 `select sum(val) from (select distinct id, val from tab1)tmp` 
. Мне надо переписать запрос без подзапроса. Возможно ли это?

не загрузился рисунок, дублирую тектом: 
   ID | VAL 
 a | 5 
 a | 5  
a | 5 
 b | 6 
 c | 5 
 c | 5 
 c | 5

Comment: А зачем избавляться от подзапроса. И так хорошо смотрится. Но если очень то вижу 2 пути: 1. выполнить join таблицы с собой с целью оставить только первые строки из повторяющихся (условие вроде id=id and rowid < rowid). 2. сделать group by id, val собрать сумму оконным sum (так как оконные функции работают уже после группировки), оставить одну строку результата (fetch next 1 rows only)

Comment: *причем для каждого а всегда будет одно и тоже значение, то есть если а=5, то оно уже не поменяется, будет встречаться в таблице несколько раз.* Покажите, как именно поддерживается это ограничение на уровне структуры таблицы (constraint). Ибо если такого ограничения нет, то все Ваши гарантии гроша ломаного не стоят - значение для одного и того же `a` может быть различно в разных записях, и, более того, когда-нибудь обязательно **будет** различным, по любой причине - сбой, ошибка, злонамеренное действие...

Comment: @Anika, таблица, которая в условии , создается путем объединения 2х таблиц и условие а=5 - это просто размноженная несколько раз одна запись. В первичной таблице не могу сумму посчиатать, так как потеряются поля, которые участвуют в соединении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Oracle должна работать такая конструкция:

```
select sum(sum(distinct VAL)) from tab1
group by ID
```

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko  Красиво!. Как понимать такой запрос: <br/> `select sum(distinct VAL) from tab1
group by ID`  <br/> Таблица разбивается на группы  и берется уникальное значение в каждой группе. Так? Снимаю шляпу.

Comment: @Akina, в Oracle точно работает. Встречала такую вложенность count(count(1))

Comment: Работает, проверил на http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/772aae/25

Comment: Значит, срабатывает некое расширение языка... Потому как данная конструкция в принципе не может ответить на вопрос "ко внутреннему или внешнему SUM применяется GROUP BY?".

Comment: Akina, ну, ко внешнему тут применяться никак не может, т.к. там уже нет ID. Т.е. когда ситуацию можно понять однозначно, Oracle нарушает требования стандарта. :-)